# VB script file system object "MoveFile" method giving permission denied error

Tags: vbscript

I have written a small script to rename a file based on an ID number within. I have never worked with vbs before, so I am still quite unfamiliar with it. I have worked out most of the issues and everything is working correctly up until the MoveFile command at the end. Just for testing purposes, I have the files saved to C:\temp and am trying to moveFile back to C:. Is this not allowed or something?
Here is my code:

```
Dim objFSO,foldername, folder, objFile, tsfiles, f1, textfile, line, filename, destinationfile
foldername = "C:\Temp"
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = objFSO.GetFolder(foldername)
Set tsfiles = folder.Files

For each f1 in tsfiles
    filename = f1.name
    textfile = foldername + "\" + filename
    If Instr(f1.name, ".TS") <> 0 Then
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile((textfile), ForReading)

        Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
            objFile.ReadLine
            line = objFile.ReadLine
            If Instr(line, "RECORDER ID:") <> 0 Then
                Dim RID 
                RID = trim(Mid(line, 15, 15))
                destinationfile = foldername + "\" + RID + ".txt"
                MsgBox(destinationfile)
                objFSO.MoveFile textfile, destinationfile
                objFile.close
            End If
        Loop
    End if
Next
```

Comment: You should really look in to using the native File operations in `System.IO` instead of creating COM objects to manipulate the file system.  The reason you can't move the file is that you still have it open from reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening then text file and the you try to move it while it's still open.  You'll have to close it prior to moving it.

Also, this ain't specific to vbscript but usually, moving files in the system drive (in your case the C:) requires administrator privileges.  I think those rules has been enforced after Windows XP so you may also need to run the script as administrator.

Comment: Well, I tried earlier to move the objFile.close command up one line (directly above the MoveFile command), and I then get an "Object Variable Not Set" error. Also, I recently acquired admin privileges on my machine, so I would hope that's not the issue...

Comment: Even if you have the admin privileges on your machine, you'll still need to execute the script as admin (right click -> Run As Administrator).

Comment: So I did end up moving the close statement to precede the rename statement. I had previously tried this and still got a permission error. So this time, I split the .MoveFile into a separated Copy and Delete for testing and found the error only occurs for attempted deletion. So I just accepted the result of not being able to delete the old file, which I do not think will matter for the purpose I am writing the script. As far as admin requirements go, the file isnt even giving me an option to run as admin. And I'm running as the owner and an admin of the machine. So idk.

Answer (score 0):

To run as admin you need to right click on it and specifically run as admin.

In your code you are trying to move while it's open. If you close it, thats fie but then it continues to go through the loop and when it tries to access the open file it fails. So you need to close it *and* break out of the loop. `Exit Do` will break out of the loop so it doesn't go back and try and evaluate `objFile.AtEndOfStream` against a closed object.

```
Dim objFSO,foldername, folder, objFile, tsfiles, f1, textfile, line, filename, destinationfile
foldername = "C:\Temp"
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = objFSO.GetFolder(foldername)
Set tsfiles = folder.Files

For each f1 in tsfiles
    filename = f1.name
    textfile = foldername + "\" + filename
    If Instr(f1.name, ".TS") <> 0 Then
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile((textfile), ForReading)

        Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
            objFile.ReadLine
            line = objFile.ReadLine
            If Instr(line, "RECORDER ID:") <> 0 Then
                Dim RID 
                RID = trim(Mid(line, 15, 15))
                destinationfile = foldername + "\" + RID + ".txt"
                MsgBox(destinationfile)
                objFile.close
                objFSO.MoveFile textfile, destinationfile
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End if
Next
```